# Wordpress MySQL query not working yet similar query works

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have the follow line of code:

```
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_pi_tourmeta (tour_id, key, content) VALUES ('15', 'attachment', 'google')");
```

This doesn't work (or return an error) yet this line of code (right below it) works perfectly:

```
$wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_pi_tours SET group_name='$group_name', director_name='$director_name', travel_dates='$travel_dates', num_passengers='$num_passengers', country_origin='$country_origin', country_dest='$country_dest', price='$price', length='$length' WHERE tour_id = '$tour_id'");
```

I have also tried INSERT INTO into the pi_tours table and that works. My syntax looks fine. The only difference is the table name, and I didn't create the table with any differences to the other ones that work. I've even tried manually inputting data into it, which works. So what the hell is going on?!?!?!

Comment: probably a duplicate key error for that `15` value? You can't insert a record with the same unique key as any other record.

Comment: The primary/unique key is an auto increment value called meta_id, so that wouldn't be a problem. Also the table is empty (we can't add anything) so that can't be the issue. @MarcB

Comment: what error is it returning?

Comment: There are no errors @aaron

Comment: try wrapping your table name with backticks (`). Also consider using prepared statement with `$wpdb->prepare`. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
`INSERT INTO wp_pi_tourmeta (tour_id, key, content) VALUES (15, 'attachment', 'google')`

instead of

`INSERT INTO wp_pi_tourmeta (tour_id, key, content) VALUES ('15', 'attachment', 'google')`.

It is interpreting `15` as a  `string` instead of an `int`

Comment: This might be helpful. Refer: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows